# Unwanted spaces in html email

Tags: html, rendering, html-email

I am trying to make an html email and I' m encountering the following issue:

I have a photoshop file that contains the layout (the images in slices and their links), which I open with Fireworks and then export as Html. When I open the Html file in a browser (Firefox, internet explorer) everything looks fine. But when I import the Html in Sendblaster (the program I use to send the newsletter) unwanted spaces appear between some of the slices. I tried sending the email to myself and the same thing happens. Any ideas how this can be fixed?

This is the code concerning two of the slices between which a space appears

```
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/MERCK-TEYXOS-final-outli-81.jpg" width="24" height="383" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="14" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5" rowspan="4">
        <img src="images/MERCK-TEYXOS-final-outli-82.jpg" width="72" height="369" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="290" alt=""></td>
</tr>
```

And this is the declaration of the table

```
    <table id="Table_01" width="885" height="2196" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Show some code examples, please.

Comment: You'll have to provide some sample code, preferably a bit that makes up a working example. Otherwise it's a guessing game for us.

Comment: E-mail requires a bit of different layout, for one xhtml 1.0 isn't supported. You'll need to use an older html version (4 I believe?). this isn't too different though. Also, have you tried using css in your tags? E.g. <td src="whateverpage" style="padding:0px" >

Comment: @poepje : I just tried using style="padding:0px" and it made no difference. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @CherryBrandy it was more of a general css tip, so you could also try things like margin:0px; or margin-left:-5px; etc. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For every image add the below inline CSS declaration, after the `alt` property and before the closing tag >

```
style="display:block;"
```

This is a common issue affecting Hotmail and Gmail - adding the CSS doesn't really affect any other clients, but it's nice to have it in there for completeness. It's worth Googling for `email display:block` for more info.